# Django/Mod_WSGI 'client denied by server configuration'

Tags: django, apache, gentoo

I'm attempting to set up Apache 2.2, Django 1.1.2 and Gentoo.  I wish to serve my project with the address: /comics

I followed the mod_wsgi directions in the django documentation to the letter, coming up with these files:

```
/etc/apache2/modules.d/70_mod_wsgi.conf

<IfDefine WSGI>
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
</IfDefine>

WSGIScriptAlias /comics /home/****/django/comicky/apache/django.wsgi
```

and

```
/home/****/django/comicky/apache/django.wsgi
import os
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/****/django')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'comicky.settings'
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

However, when I attempt to load the page, I get this in /var/log/apache2/error_log:

```
client denied by server configuration: /home/****/django/comicky/apache/django.wsgi
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like a permissions issue from your conf file.  See, for example:

- [Apache Error: Client denied by server configuration](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/ClientDeniedByServerConfiguration)

Comment: I have       
    "AllowOveride All"
    "Order allow,deny"
    "Allow from all"

Comment: is correct, this indicates that you haven't correctly told Apache that it can serve up that resource. See my talk slides at http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/downloads/detail?name=mod_wsgi-pycon-sydney-2010.pdf where I explicitly show this. If you go to wiki on mod_wsgi site you will also find link to video of talk.

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't include the necessary <Directory> directives.  I only had "/", not the actual folder of my app.  That problem is solved.  Now just to resolve some weird library issues, but I won't make you guys fix that one for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your conf file matches this: [conf sample file](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/). I had to add the wsgi.py at the end to make mine work